# Comparing two arrays element wise in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames.
My final goal is to compare a column in both data frames and return those values which donot match with each other
example:

```
df_1["column_1"]= ["A45", "kl24", "mhg", "tz22" ]
df_2["column_2"]= ["KL24", "tz22", "mhg", "A 45"]
```

I need a code that comparing two array values in the respective dataframe["column"] and returns those values from df_1 which did not match in df_2(Ex: from our example "A45" and "kl24" will return because there is a space and upper and lower case error)

Can anyone kindly please help me with this !

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: @TCMolenaar. First of all thanks a lot for the answer. I will try it out in an hour. Currently occupied with other stuff

Comment: @TCMolenaar -Hi   "df = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer', left_on='column_1', right_on='column_2', indicator=True)" I am getting a memory error for this step. Maybe my laptop is not strong enough to deal with it. Can you show me another approach please?

Comment: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.3 GiB for an array with shape (7, 198409634) and data type float64

Comment: Try `how='left'`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.merge(..., how='left', indicator=True)` and select the rows with `left_only`:

```
>>> df = df_1.merge(df_2, how='outer', left_on='column_1', right_on='column_2', indicator=True)
>>> df
  column_1 column_2      _merge
0      A45      NaN   left_only
1     kl24      NaN   left_only
2      mhg      mhg        both
3     tz22     tz22        both
4      NaN     KL24  right_only
5      NaN     A 45  right_only
>>> df[df._merge == 'left_only']['column_1']
0     A45
1    kl24
Name: column_1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.isin` and `df.loc` to do the trick

```
df_1["column_1"].loc[~df_1["column_1"].isin(df_2["column_2"])]

  column_1
0      A45
1     kl24
```

Comment: I am getting an error as   "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__"

Comment: @ar_mm18 This is the first time I saw this error. Are you trying to do for loop using this code? Perhaps you can share more sample data in your post. Perhaps upgrade your Pandas version or changing your data to `str` type as in this link https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/issues/671

Comment: I have updated the code too. I think the `instancecheck` is not posted in your question. It is different from the question you have asked here